# How can I set up Evolution to access a local mail box?

Tags: evolution, email

Often, when I start up a new terminal, I get the message:
`No mail for pwnguin`, or `You have 5 unread messages`. I'm not terribly great with `mail`, but I do have a running instance of Evolution connecting to a Zimbra account. How can I set up Evolution to also monitor this local inbox?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This answer follows the premise that you're using a mail spool, if its mbox format your mileage may vary:

- Start Evolution, then go to Tools -> *Settings*.
- Click *Mail Accounts* -> *Add* -> *Forward*.
- Type in a name in the *Full Name* field.
- For the *Email Address* field, type in your login ID followed by @localhost. For example: `lazypower@localhost` Click *Forward*.
- Click on the drop down list box and select *Local delivery*. If the *Path* field in the Configuration section isn't already filled in, you'll need to type in the location of your local mailbox. Using the login ID from above as an example, here's what would be entered: `/var/spool/mail/lazypower` Click *Forward*.
- If you like, you can setup Evolution to automatically check this
  mail account. Click *Forward*.
- You're not going to be sending mail with this account, so you could just leave everything alone in the *Sending Email* window. However, I change the *Server Type* to *Sendmail*. Click *Forward*.
- Finally, enter a name for the mail account. The name *"Local Messages"* is a good choice. Click *Forward* and *Apply*.

Thanks go to [this post](http://dotancohen.com/howto/root_email.html) I've verified the instructions locally. Works without a hitch.

Comment: Thanks. I think what was confusing me is that while evolution adds a "username@localhost" entry in the mail sidebar, the mail will be in the "on this computer" folders.

Comment: I have a different version of Evolution, but I was able to accomplish the same tasks via Edit -> Preferences -> Mail Accounts -> Add and then selecting a local mbox spool file.

Answer (score -1):

Try using localhost for all server names (incoming/outgoing mail server,etc) in evolution and then the usual usernames and passwords. The email address will probably also follow the username@localhost format.

Comment: Error while Scanning folders in "IMAP server localhost".
Could not connect to localhost: Connection refused

Comment: I think this is "local delivery", so it's mbox protocol. The question is, then, how to configure evolution to find the mbox.

Comment: The question didn't mention mbox...

Comment: It also didn't mention smtp or imap. I just know it's some kind of local delivery. Could be spooling, I don't know.